# asp.net dropdown listbox not holding viewstate

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, submit

I am using VS 2008, VB and using a dorpdown listbox in my asp.net webpage. I select a value from the dropdown, click the submit button, when the page comes back from the server, the value in the dropdown is blank (default). The dropdown controls viewstate is enabled.

The code for the submit button is:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="Button" />
```

The dropdownlist code is:

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the code that you have that checks the dropdown list value?

Comment: If ddlMonth.SelectedValue <> "" Then

Comment: what about the selectedIndex property? is it blank? can you show the ddl asp.net code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you binding dropdown in page_load event? If yes move that code in

```
 if(!page.isPostback)
    {
       binddropdown();
    }
```

Comment: I need a vacation.. Thanks rs